# regex javascript to add to expression

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime

I have to write a few regexes. I did all except the following. I don't know how to add something via regex only.

- Change this  `9/28/2005`  to  `09.28.2005`  (Am able to replace slashes with period but how to add leading zero to 9)
- Change `September 21, 2006` to `21. September 2006` (am able to replace `,` with `.` but how to change the order?)
- Change `5:00 PM` to `i7:00 Uhr`   (12 to 24 hour)?

Comment: Use a callback in the `replace()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st Case (padding with zero):**

```
result = subject.replace(/\b(\d)(?=[\/.])/ig, "0$1");
```

**2nd Case (change order):**

```
result = subject.replace(/\b(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december) +(\d{2}), +(\d{2,4})\b/ig, "$2. $1 $3");
```

**3rd case (12-24 hr)**

As JavaScript RegEx engine does not support `If-Then-Else Conditionals`. So, it is hard and time-taking job to create a `pure RegEx pattern` for that purpose.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response . In both case 1 and case 2 months and day can be or not be two digits long, like 01 or 1. In case its only 1 i need to add leading zero . In case its 01. i dont have to add leading zero. This is missing in 2nd case. Can u plz help .

Comment: You could redirect output of your 2nd case to the input of first case. And the problem would be solved.

Comment: I dont get it, can u plz explain with some example.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the math manually... e.g. make a function GetTimeZoneOffset and go from there...

Return the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time:

`var d = new Date()`

`var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();`

The resulting value of `n` will be: `240`

Add the difference and viola you have a real date which you can format what way you want..